# Implementing routing in haskell HTTP server

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a simple way to route requests based on the hostname. Here is the function:

```
handleAccept :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
handleAccept handle hostname = do
    putStrLn $ "Handling request from " ++ (getMessage hostname)
    request <- fmap (parseRequest . lines) (hGetContents handle)
    respond request handle
    return ()
    where getMessage x
        | x == "hello" = "hello route"
        | x == "LOL" = "what's so funny?"
        | otherwise = x
```

Called here:

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    sock <- listenOn (PortNumber 9000)
    putStrLn "Listening on port 9000"
    forever $ do
        (handle, hostname, port) <- accept sock
        handleAccept handle hostname
        hClose handle
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

at this line in `handleAccept`:

```
where getMessage x
        | x == "hello" = "hello route"
```

There seems to be an issue using guards with a where statement. So I tried this dummy function:

```
wherePlusGuards :: String -> Bool
wherePlusGuards x = getX x
    where getX x
        | x == "hello" = True
        | otherwise = False
```

This compiles fine. I'm left to believe that the issue is coming from using a where statement and guards *inside* a `do` expression. Why is this the case? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `|` is indented further than the `g` in `getMessage` - e.g.:

```
import System.IO

handleAccept :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
handleAccept handle hostname = do
    putStrLn $ "Handling request from " ++ (getMessage hostname)
    return ()
    where getMessage x
           | x == "hello" = "hello route"
           | x == "LOL" = "what's so funny?"
           | otherwise = x
```

**Update**

This does not parse correctly:

```
wherePlusGuards :: String -> Bool
wherePlusGuards x = getX x
    where getX x
        | x == "hello" = True
        | otherwise = False
```

It yields the error: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Note: I'm not using any tabs.

From the Haskell2010 Report:

> Note 1. A nested context must be further indented than the enclosing context (n > m). If not, L fails, and the compiler should indicate a layout error.

Reference: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html

Section 10.3 (Layout), Note 1.

Comment: why would that matter? What is the indent count that the parser looks for?

Comment: Answer updated - are you sure about `wherePlusGuards` parsing ok? it doesn't parse for me.

Comment: Reference from the Haskell Report added.

Comment: interesting... it compiles when i use tabs. thanks for clearing that up.